# How to determine what vbscripts are running in background

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a vbscript to determine what are the vbscripts running in background but when I execute my script . it only opens the folder of my script not the other scripts location or folder . What should I do?? Please help

Myscript.vbs

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
strPath = "explorer.exe /e," & strFolder
objShell.Run strPath
```

Please help guys . I am very new to vbscript .

Comment: You cannot tell from the file explorer what scripts are running. You will need to examine the running processes instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have for you an old vbscript since 2015 that can tell you what vbscript is running in the background with its command line of course to get their paths and you have a possiblity to choose what vbscript you want to kill and you get in the end of the script a log file for this.

So you can give a try for this first, and i will edit and update it for any modifications in order to answer your question.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Copyright,fso,ws,NomFichierLog,temp,PathNomFichierLog,OutPut,Count
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,_
    "There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit
Else 
    Copyright = "[Hackoo "& chr(169) & " 2015]"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = CreateObject( "Wscript.Shell" )
    NomFichierLog="Killed_Process.txt"
    temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
    PathNomFichierLog = temp & "\" & NomFichierLog
    Set OutPut = fso.CreateTextFile(temp & "\" & NomFichierLog,1)
    Call Find("wscript.exe")
    Call Explorer(PathNomFichierLog)
End If
'***************************************************************************************************
Function Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Explorer "& File & "\",1,True
end Function
'***************************************************************************************************
Sub Find(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,Processus,Question,Msg
    Titre = " Process(es) "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" running "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    Count = 0 
    For Each objItem in colItems
        Count= Count + 1
        Processus = objItem.CommandLine
        Question = MsgBox ("Would do you like to kill this script : " & DblQuote(Processus) & " ?" ,VBYesNO+VbQuestion,Titre+Copyright)
        If Question = VbYes then
            objItem.Terminate(0)'To kill the process
            OutPut.WriteLine Processus
        else
            Count= Count - 1 'decrementing the count of -1
        End if
    Next
    OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*")
    If Count > 1 Then
        Msg = " were killed"
    Else
        Msg = " was killed"
    End if
    OutPut.WriteLine count & Titre & Msg
    OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*") & VbCrLF 
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

***EDIT : Extract_CommandLine.bat***

Copy and paste this code as batch file in order to extract the command line of each process.

`Set ProcessNames="cmd.exe" "mshta.exe" "powershell.exe" "cscript.exe" "wscript.exe"`

You can add or remove the process name from the variable `ProcessNames` between the double quotes.

```
@echo off
Title Extract CommandLine Of Running Processes by Hackoo 2020
Mode 110,10 & color 0A
Set "TmpFile=%~n0_Abs_cmdline.txt"
Set "LogFile=%~n0_cmdline.txt
If Exist "%TmpFile%" Del "%TmpFile%"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
Set ProcessNames="cmd.exe" "mshta.exe" "powershell.exe" "cscript.exe" "wscript.exe" 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (%ProcessNames%) Do (
    Call :GetCommandLine %%A ProcessCmd
    If defined ProcessCmd ( 
        echo !ProcessCmd!>con
        echo !ProcessCmd!>>"%TmpFile%"
    )
)
Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak>nul
If Exist "%TmpFile%" Call :Extract "%TmpFile%" "%LogFile%"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Start "" "%LogFile%"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Call :ExplorerIT "%LogFile%"
Exit
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetCommandLine <ProcessName> <ProcessCmd>
Set "ProcessCmd="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%P in (
'wmic process where caption^="%~1" get commandline /format:list ^| findstr /I "%~1" ^| find /I /V "%~nx0" 2^>nul'
) do (
    if not defined %2 Set "%2=%%P"
)
Exit /b
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Extract <InputData> <OutPutData>
(
echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
echo Data = Extract(Data,"(^?^!.*(\x22\w^)^)\b.*(\w^).*(\.ps1^|\.hta^|\.vbs^|\.vbe^|\.cmd^|\.bat^|\.lnk^)"^)
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Data
echo Function Extract(Data,Pattern^)
echo    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
echo    set oRE = New RegExp
echo    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
echo    oRE.Global = True
echo    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
echo    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data^)
echo    If not isEmpty(oMatches^) then
echo        For Each Match in oMatches  
echo            Line = Line ^& chr(34^) ^& Trim(Match.Value^) ^& chr(34^) ^& vbcrlf
echo        Next
echo        Extract = Line 
echo    End if
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:ExplorerIT <LogFile>
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%~1"') do (
    Start "SelectFile" Explorer /select,"%%~a"
)
Exit /B
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you :-) .. can I execute this script using cscript command from command line?

Comment: @Maximious Just give a try for my last updated code with a batch file and name it as `Extract_CommandLine.bat` and execute it ! and tell me the result !

Comment: @Maximious if this dosn't answer your question i will delete it !

Comment: sorry I didn't executed this script yet . I will tell you on 18-07-2020 saturday . I need some time man

Comment: @Maximious ok and don't forget that the last code is a batch and not a vbscript !